# iframe not displayed in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, compatibility

half way through building a website an iframe on my page has disappeared when the webpage is viewed in chrome. The iframe is still visible in firefox, ie, safari and opera. All browsers are up to date.

```
<body>
<div id="apDiv9" style="text-align: center; position: fixed;"><ul id="menu">
<li></li>
<li><a href="newarrivals.html" target="content">New Arrivals</a>    </li>
<li><a href="yardsale.html" target="content">Yard Sale</a>    </li>
<li><a href="carsale.html" target="content">Car Sales</a>    </li>
<li><a href="houserental.html" target="content">House Rental</a></li>
<li><a href="hotspots.php" target="content">Hot Spots</a>    </li>
<li>
  <a href="events.html" target="content">Events</a>    </li>
<li>
    <a href="chatter.html" target="content">Chatter</a>
<li></li><iframe height="30px" width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" id="frmFile"     src="marquee.html" onload="LoadFile();"></iframe>
      </ul>
</li>
```

This is the iframe which sources a marquee from a seperate html file, it sits just under the menu. Please help. I have only included a snippet of code.

***The error in the chrome console says Uncaught ReferenceError: LoadFile is not defined***

Comment: That's probably because your HTML is invalid. You cannot put an iframe tag in outside of an LI in a list like that.

Comment: `the iframe which sources a marquee` Marquee!? I thought we all decided to stop using those in like 1999.

Comment: @Diodeus that doesn't seem to explain why it did work and then suddenly stopped, or why it worked in all the other browsers. ?? :(

Comment: I have tried the iframe in its own div all over the page and still nothing so it does not seem to be the positioning of the iframe, more the iframe itself simply not working in Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line form your HTML `<head>` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-FRAME-OPTIONS" content="DENY">
```