# iframe suddenly not appearing in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, compatibility

half way through building a website an iframe on my page has disappeared when the webpage is viewed in chrome. The iframe is still visible in firefox, ie, safari and opera. All browsers are up to date. It was working fine up until a point, however I do not know what that point was!

```
<body>
<div id="apDiv9" style="text-align: center; position: fixed;"><ul id="menu">
<li></li>
<li><a href="newarrivals.html" target="content">New Arrivals</a>    </li>
<li><a href="yardsale.html" target="content">Yard Sale</a>    </li>
<li><a href="carsale.html" target="content">Car Sales</a>    </li>
<li><a href="houserental.html" target="content">House Rental</a></li>
<li><a href="hotspots.php" target="content">Hot Spots</a>    </li>
<li>
  <a href="events.html" target="content">Events</a>    </li>
<li>
    <a href="chatter.html" target="content">Chatter</a>
<li></li><iframe height="30px" width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" id="frmFile"     src="marquee.html" onload="LoadFile();"></iframe>
      </ul>
</li>
```

This is the iframe which sources a marquee from a seperate html file, it sits just under the menu. Please help. I have only included a snippet of code. I only have the ability to test locally too :)

***The error in the chrome console says Uncaught ReferenceError: LoadFile is not defined***

Comment: why do you have opening and closing li tags before the iframe? try putting the closing tag at the end and see if it works then. Try including the full path too.

Comment: your list item isn't closed after Chatter either

Comment: I put it at the end just before the closing div and still nothing :(. I tried it all over the page so it does not seem to be the positioning of the iframe, more the iframe itself

Comment: possible duplicate of [iframe not displayed in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22918353/iframe-not-displayed-in-chrome)